# How can I detect if a browser supports a viewport unit, like vh or dvh?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm planning to make very responsive website. For this, I'm including external stylesheet currently.

But I want to include it for only those browsers which supports viewport units such as vw.

So, how could I detect for browser that it supports or not.

Please note: I don't want to include modernizer.

Comment: "I don't want to include modernizer.": why not? [Seems like the simplest way of detecting vw units](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24108004/1377002).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code that `Modernizr` uses:

```
  testStyles('#modernizr { width: 50vw; }', function(elem) {
    var width = parseInt(window.innerWidth / 2, 10);
    var compStyle = parseInt((window.getComputedStyle ?
                              getComputedStyle(elem, null) :
                              elem.currentStyle).width, 10);

    Modernizr.addTest('cssvwunit', compStyle == width);
  });
```

So you can do something similar. Just follow these steps:

1. Set an element with `width` in `vw`.
2. Check the computed `width` of the element to match the viewport's width.
3. If both are same, then your browser supports `vw` and `vh`!

*Snippet coming soon...*

```js
$(function () {
  elemWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#checkVw"), null).width, 10);
  halfWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth / 2, 10);
  $("#checkVw").html("Your browser" + ((elemWidth == halfWidth) ? "" : "does not ") + " support VW and VH");
});
```

```css
#checkVw { width: 50vw; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkVw"></div>
```

I checked with IE 7 and it screwed up! `;)`

Answer (score 10):

In modern browsers you can use [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) in CSS to check support for various things, including viewport units.

Wrap any styles you wish in `@supports` much like [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) queries:

```
@supports(height: 100vh) {
 .myClass { height: 100vh; }
}
```

This example tests to see if a browser supports units like `vh` or `dvh` or a non-existing type of `madeup` (i.e. a type that your browser does not know about):

```css
#supportVH::after, #supportDVH:after, #supportMadeUp:after {
    content: "❌ NO";
  color: white;
  background-color: darkred;
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@supports(height: 100vh) {
    #supportVH::after {
        content: "✅ YES";
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}

@supports(height: 100dvh) {
    #supportDVH:after {
        content: "✅ YES";
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}

@supports(height: 100madeup) {
    #supportMadeUp:after {
        content: "✅ YES";
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="supportVH">Does your browser support <code>vh</code>?</div>
<div id="supportDVH">Does your browser support <code>dvh</code>?</div>
<div id="supportMadeUp">Does your browser support <code>madeup</code>?</div>
```

In JavaScript you can use it the same way with [`CSS.supports()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports):

```
const supportsDvh = CSS.supports('height: 100dvh');
```